# Can I run Flask and Neo4j in the same container?

Tags: python, docker, flask, neo4j

I am new to the Docker world. My folder looks like the following:

```
app/
   __init__.py
   api.py
   data_loader.py
```

First I run `data_loader.py` to load data to a Neo4j database.
Then I start the flask server as `python -m app.api`.

The flask API expects a local Neo4j db, so I want both flask and Neo4j in same Docker container.  How do I go about this?  I am confused by the differences between the Dockerfile and Docker Compose.

Answer (score 1):

You generally want to run only one program in a container.  This is especially true if one of those programs is a database, and one an application that stores data there: you want to be able to replace the application container while leaving the database running, and in a production environment you could want to run multiple application containers for scale and redundancy but still have a single copy of the database.

Docker Compose is a standard tool, driven by a YAML file, that lets you describe multiple containers that need to work together:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  application:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    environment:
      NEO4J_HOST: database # see below
  database:
    image: neo4j:4.2 # https://hub.docker.com/_/neo4j
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Each container is its own `localhost`, so you need to configure the application to look somewhere else for the database.  The Compose service names `application` and `database` are usable as host names, within this Docker environment (not by other Compose setups, not by browser applications even if they're served out of Docker, and not directly from the host).  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes this further.

This means your application will need some way to configure the database location.  An environment variable is easy to use:

```py
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
import os

db_host = os.environ.get('NEO4J_HOST', 'localhost')
db_port = os.environ.get('NEO4J_PORT', '7687')
driver = GraphDatabase.Driver(f'neo4j://{db_host}:{db_port}')
```

The defaults here are fine for your host non-Docker development environment.  In your `docker-compose.yml` file you can specify alternate environment variable settings, which is the `environment:` block from above.

In production you could very reasonably want to run the database somewhere else: if your cloud provider has a hosted version of Neo4j you could use that, or you could want to run the database on dedicated hardware, even if the rest of the system runs in Docker.  The environment-variable mechanism lets you configure this as needed; it is not specific to Docker.

You shouldn't need to do anything special in your Dockerfile.  The Python Neo4j driver doesn't appear to have special host requirements, so it's enough to include it in your `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` and build a plain Python-application image.  Don't include the database location or credentials in your source code or Dockerfile (beyond the developer-oriented defaults if the environment variables aren't set).